# Size transition on a Sliver

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I am looking to animate `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar` size to 0 programatically. I was looking for a `SliverSizeTransition` or `SliverAnimatedContainer` or something like that but couldn't find one.

There is `SliverAnimatedOpacity` but that only animates the opacity and not the height. Currently hacking by scrolling by some 50 offset along with animating the opacity.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but try :

```
SliverToBoxAdapter( 
    child: AnimatedContainer(..),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AnimatedSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSize-class.html) widget:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: AnimatedSize(
      duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
      child: SizedBox(
      height: showSection ? 100 : 0,
      child: SuggestedBlockList(),
      ),
    ),
),
```